# Decryption algo for AES in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

```
public static String Encrypt(String text){
    try {           
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);

        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String result = Base64.encodeToString(results, 0);
        //result = URLEncoder.encode(result.trim(),"UTF-8");
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return null;
    }
}   

public static String Decrypt(String text){
    try {           
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);
        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String result = Base64.encodeToString(results, 0);
        //result = URLEncoder.encode(result.trim(),"UTF-8");
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("decryption", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is code for encryption and decryption, I got encryption algo from some other question and it works fine for me but I need to decrypt too and I tried to mimic it like encryption but its not working. Exception says last block incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're not performing the reverse sequence in the reverse order. You've ended up with base64-encoded data - so the first thing you need to do is base64-decode that to get to the *binary* encrypted data. Then decrypt, then convert that back to a string using UTF-8.

```
public static String decrypt(String text){
    try {           
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] b= KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len= b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);
        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(text, 0));
        return new String(results, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("decryption", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

When you take code from somewhere, it's important that you really understand what it's doing - in particular, understand what the data is like at each stage here:

- Start with plain text
- UTF-8 encode that to a byte array
- Encrypt to another byte array (which *isn't* UTF-8-encoded text)
- Base64 encode the encrypted binary data to a string

Any time you're doing a transformation like this, when you want to reverse it you need to reverse the order of the steps too, in order to get back to the original data.